# Search Data using Models in Laravel 5.4.36

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have created a search filter. Basically I'm getting records from single table so it works fine. But when i try to get data from another table, it is not correct. This is my **drivers_table** (driver_id is PK)

[image: Drivers Table]

I'm using this query..

```
$drivers = Drivers::where('city', 'like', "$keywords[0]%")
            ->Where('first_name', 'like', "$keywords[1]%")
            ->get();
```

I have two dropdowns, Lets suppose I have 50 drivers, When i select City `"DOHA"` from first dropdown, Using ajax it gets me records of 20 drivers out of 50, and then i select first_name `"ASFAND"` from 2nd dropdown, it gets me records of people whose first name is Asfand from that list of 20 drivers. There was 5 people whose name was Asfand and also they were from DOHA City ( because i have selected both `DOHA as city` from first dropdown and `first_name` as Asfand from second drop down.

Everything works perfect. But now my question is I have a 3rd dropdown from which i will select Bank name, but bank name is not in the Drivers table, There is another table.

**Banks** (id, driver_id, bank_name)..

[image: Banks Table]

How can i get records now?

```
$drivers = DB::table('drivers')
            ->join('bank','bank.driver_id','=','drivers.driver_id')
            ->where('city', 'like', "$keywords[0]%")
            ->Where('first_name', 'like', "$keywords[1]%")
            ->orWhere('bank.bank_name', 'like', "$keywords[3]%")
            ->get();
```

Now if i select doha from first dropdown it doesnot show me any record.. if i select bank name from 3rd dropdown then it shows me record.. I want dropdowns to be independent..

If i don't select anything from 3rd dropdown, it should still show what i selected from first two dropdowns.

Comment: Try leftjoin instead, 
->leftJoin('bank','bank.driver_id','=','drivers.driver_id')

Comment: I have tried `leftJoin` but still it doesn't

Comment: Not tested but should work..
->where(DB::raw("(city LIKE '$keywords[1]%' AND first_name LIKE '$keywords[1]%' ) OR bank.bank_name LIKE '$keywords[3]%' "))

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
$drivers = DB::table('drivers')
        ->join('bank','bank.driver_id','=','drivers.driver_id')
        ->where(function($query) use ($keywords) {
            $query->where('drivers.city', 'like', "$keywords[0]%")
                  ->orWhere('drivers.first_name', 'like', "$keywords[1]%")
                  ->orWhere('bank.bank_name', 'like', "$keywords[3]%");
        })           
        ->toSql();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($drivers);
die();
```

Check with this it prints your query, try it in sql, if it working in that with your criteria then its perfect.

Comment: Here i used or where condition so that it check for first if it is no blank if blank then go to second and further...

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins only when it is required.

```
 $drivers = DB::table('drivers')
        ->where('city', 'like', "$keywords[0]%")
        ->where('first_name', 'like', "$keywords[1]%")
        ->when(!empty($keywords[3]), function ($query) use ($keywords) {
            $query->join('bank','bank.driver_id','=','drivers.driver_id')
            $query->where('bank.bank_name', 'like', $keywords[3].'%');
        })
```

Comment: It gives an error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$driver_id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$query = Drivers::query();
            $query->leftjoin('bank','bank.driver_id','=','drivers.driver_id');
            $query->where(function ($query) use($keywords){
                  $query->where('city', 'LIKE', "$keywords[0]%")
                             ->orwhere('first_name', 'LIKE', "$keywords[1]%")
                             ->orwhere('bank.bank_name', 'LIKE', "%$keywords[3]%");
            });
            $query->get();
```

Comment: It gives me error `You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances`

Comment: Can you please post query here?